# removing the need for {ldelim} and {rdelim} in JavaScript within Smarty 2 templates

Tags: javascript, smarty, templating, error-logging, smarty2

I have the following block of JavaScript in a Smarty 2 template file.

The code is verbatim to what has been provided to me from the provider, but it quite noticable that I have had to add in a number of `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}` Smarty tags in to replace the JavaScript `{` and `}`.

I need to feed in the `$log_id`, that won't change, however is there a way for me to write this cleaner without the need for all these tags making the code look less readable?

I am aware of the `{literal}` tag, but opening and closing that tag would arguably make it less readable.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.Muscula = {ldelim} settings:{ldelim}
        logId:"{$log_id}", suppressErrors: false, branding: 'none'
    {rdelim}};
    (function () {ldelim}
        var m = document.createElement('script'); m.type = 'text/javascript'; m.async = true;
        m.src = (window.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//musculahq.appspot.com/Muscula.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(m, s);
        window.Muscula.run=function(c){ldelim}eval(c);window.Muscula.run=function(){ldelim}{rdelim};{rdelim};
        window.Muscula.errors=[];window.onerror=function(){ldelim}window.Muscula.errors.push(arguments);
        return window.Muscula.settings.suppressErrors===undefined;{rdelim}
    {rdelim})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you may change smarty delimiter

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.escaping.tpl

```
<?php

$smarty->left_delimiter = '{{';
$smarty->right_delimiter = '}}';

$smarty->assign('log_id', 'something');

?>
```

Your template would them become:

**(note the double brackets for variables {{$variable}} )**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.Muscula = { settings:{
        logId:"{{$log_id}}", suppressErrors: false, branding: 'none'
    } };
    (function () {
        var m = document.createElement('script'); m.type = 'text/javascript'; m.async = true;
        m.src = (window.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//musculahq.appspot.com/Muscula.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(m, s);
        window.Muscula.run=function(c){eval(c);window.Muscula.run=function(){};};
        window.Muscula.errors=[];window.onerror=function(){window.Muscula.errors.push(arguments);
        return window.Muscula.settings.suppressErrors===undefined;}
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is possible to change the delimiters in this way. However, I am finding that this is then preventing the variable `$log_id` from being parsed meaning that the following is output: `logId:"{$log_id}"`. So I don't think this completely solves my problem.

Comment: I've tried changing the delimiters as in your example, and then adding the double braces - but this still parses as `logId:"{{$log_id}}"`. I am using Smarty 2.6.9 - is this supported in that version?

Comment: I think so. Are you inside of a {literal} tag?

Comment: No, I have no `{literal}` tags. The feedback i'm getting from Smarty themselves is to either use `{literal}`, `{ldelim}` tags or upgrade to Smarty 3. Sadly I can't do that without significant work, so it looks like my template may have to be a touch clumsly looking.

Comment: can you show us your PHP code? (where you render your template)